# What is the symbol # used for in C#

Tags: c#, region

I'm not that experienced with programming and I encountered the `#` symbol in a piece of C# code. So what is the # used for in `#region`?

```
public class DatabaseIndex : IComparable<DatabaseIndex>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region DataBaseIndex
        public DatabaseIndex(DatabasePackedFile owner)
        {
            this.Owner = owner;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
        {
        ...
        }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/

Comment: For info their use can indicate overly long methods or overly large classes and in general I'd discourage their use (I believe some tools warn against them) - see here for more info https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell

Comment: The suggested duplicates don’t directly address the `#`, which introduces a preprocessor directive. The dupes do give good examples of how preprocessor directives work. For info on the specific directive `#region`, check the compiler docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used to denote preprocessor directives, in this case defining a block of code that can expand/collapse when using visual studio, to make it easier to maintain for future developer.

You can read more about them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/

Answer (score 3):

#region #endregion pair 
it's used to maintain readability and order in your code.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This means this is a region of code... Basically, it is a way to group code within a file.  It is esentially a comment. Visual studio will allow you to collapse/expand regions. When working with large files, this is very helpful.

```
#region MyCode
...your code
#end region
```